# I have a crate of out of date beer/bitter by 6 months, tastes watery, can I resurrect it in some way?

Tags: ingredients, age

I found a case of Scottish beer / bitter that I had forgotten about, it is out of date by 7 months, which normally would not stop me but it tastes watery. My question is can I re-ferment it or add something to resurrect it?

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't have any carbonation? Could you list the beer so I/the community knows more of what the beer should taste like?

Comment: *unable to comment*, but refermenting is dependent on whether the beer is a [real ale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cask_ale), which means that yeast is still active in the beer. If you know anything about the style or age, that would be useful information, but most likely, you can make a beer cocktail, (use google for recipes for certain styles) or something like a michelada out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt it. What happens over time is that chemicals giving the taste decays, and you cannot magically make them appear. You could perhaps add something to give it taste, but then, is it still beer?

Refermenting (could be done by adding sugar) will give carbon dioxide and alcohol, but not more taste.

Answer (score 0):

Could pour it into something like [this](http://shop.dogfish.com/store/barware/other-accessories/randall-jr.htm) and infuse it with more hops or adjuncts.

Comment: Hi newGuy, can you please expand your answer to include more detail?  If the link becomes invalid, there will be no context to understand what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a beer with a high alcohol percentage (say 7%+) I'd just throw it out, life's too short to drink stale beer.

Otherwise you can test several bottles. You might get lucky with a few, not every bottle in the same case ages at the same rate, certainly if it's one with fermentation on the bottle.

**tip**: If you hear a hiss when opening the bottle, it's safe to taste. I never trust a bottle that's silent when opening as it almost guarantees that it's gone bad.